Bricks SE - Year in Review 2017
2017 has been a particularly memorable year for Bricks SE, most notably for the new relationship that had been established between the site and The LEGO Group. 
Through the various community events, we were given the valuable opportunity to meet LEGO community members.

Very nice! Thanks for putting all of this together in one place.

Event Timeline
'Becoming a recognized LEGO User Group' - 11th January
In January, jncraton successfully applied for Bricks SE to become a recognized LEGO User Group. Since early February jncraton has been our sites ambassador to The LEGO Group.
Related: 'New recognition status with TLG' - 11th December

'LEGO Answers is now Bricks' - 21st April
To respect TLG wishes to to protect the LEGO brand and trademark, the community decided to rename LEGO® Answers to Bricks Stack Exchange. 
Aside from the change in name, we are still the same site question and answer site for LEGO and building block enthusiasts.

'LEGO Fan Media Days 2017 - Trip Report' - 6th June
For the first time ever, Bricks Stack Exchange had been given the opportunity, to attend an official LEGO event since becoming a Recognised Fan Media site.

'TLG Support for Boost questions' - 6th June
LEGO provided us with a copy of the LEGO Boost kit to facilitate answering questions about this new product.

'Enfield Trip Report' - 17th September
LUG Ambassador jncraton attended RLFM event in Enfield, USA to connect with the Lego Community Engagement team and fellow Fan Media communities.

'LEGO House AFOL Opening Event - Trip Report' - 23rd September
Community moderator Zhaph - Ben Duguid attended the LEGO House AFOL Opening Event in Billund, Denmark.

'Win a LEGO set prize for participating in Winter Bash 2017!' - 15th Dec
To coincide with the yearly network wide Winter Bash events, Bricks SE hosted a prize draw for those who participated and earned three or more hats during the holiday season.

2017 Statistics
Most Viewed Quesitons
Question                                                                    Views 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------- 
How do I center a 2x2 plate on a 3x3 plate?                                  10534     
The LEGO Logo Font                                                           7592      
What is this light grey LEGO plate with six sides?                           3059      
Why is LEGO usually uppercase?                                               2449      
LEGO Mindstorms 9797 (NXT Education base set) Software Download              2389      
How should I arrange LEGO to sell per pound?                                 2026      
Can you identify this bevelled grey 2x1 piece?                               1940      
What is this piece slightly longer than a 2x2 plate with grooves and a hole? 1851      
Can you identify these 20 year old LEGO sets?                                1822      
What are the programming languages that can be used on Lego Mindstorm EV3?   1629   

New Users by Month
Month New Users
----- ----------
1     131       
2     150       
3     107       
4     176       
5     109       
6     95        
7     118       
8     104       
9     123       
10    115       
11    164       
12    210   

All Time Statistics
New Users per Year
Year New Users 
---- --------- 
2011 533       
2012 627       
2013 797       
2014 910       
2015 1010      
2016 1101      
2017 1602  

Edits per Year
Year Edits 
---- ----- 
2011 602   
2012 434   
2013 436   
2014 509   
2015 538   
2016 711   
2017 1148 

Comments per Year
Year Comments 
---- -------- 
2011 1086     
2012 905      
2013 848      
2014 876      
2015 987      
2016 876      
2017 960   

Voting per Year
Year Accepts Upvotes Downvotes 
---- ------- ------- --------- 
2011 170     4970    140       
2012 148     4596    102       
2013 133     3711    137       
2014 143     5396    197       
2015 166     4592    285       
2016 152     3633    365       
2017 169     5385    269     

Posts per Year
Year Questions Answers 
---- --------- ------- 
2011 237       509     
2012 248       459     
2013 263       489     
2014 352       623     
2015 399       633     
2016 364       602     
2017 425       559    

Source: SE Data query

It's great to see that we had the most new users, posts, and edits in 2017!

I know it wouldn't be in the SEDE yet but this one would be in third on the most viewed list.

@David Well spotted! I will try and check back later to see if it has changed.
